# Question re parametric identity

Tags: parametric

I am asking whether the existence of a parametric identity involving a set of quadruple signed integers $\{i, j, k, l\}$, which is true for infinitely many sets of quadruples for each integer value of $n, (n>0)$, implies that there is a relationship between some or all of the variables in the set $\{i, j, k, l\}$ and/or relationship between some (or all) of the parameters of the $\{i, j, k, l\}$ with $n$?
And furthermore, I am asking whether such relationship would allow rewriting the parametric identity to hold true for subsets of the $\{i, j, k, l\}$ set that contain fewer than four parameters and perhaps involve direct relationship with $n$?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether this is the kind of thing you have in mind:
$n=(i^2-j^2)-(k^2-l^2)$ has infinitely many integer solutions for each integer $n>0$.
I don't think this implies any relation among some or all of $i,j,k,l$ (unless you allow relations that also involve $n$).
But one does have $2r=(r+s+1)^2-(r+s)^2-((s+1)^2-s^2)$ which uses only two parameters, and has infinitely many solutions for each $r$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry - I meant to allow relations that also involve n. I edited my question to make it clear. Sorry for confusion and thanks for answering.

Comment: OK, then I'm not sure what you mean by a parametric identity involving $i,j,k,l$, true for infinitely many quadruples for each $n$ – that sounds to me like a relation among the parameters and $n$. Maybe you can give an example?

Comment: Proposition 1. For every n ∈ N, it is possible to find infinitely many quadruples (i, j, k, l) ∈ Z that fulfil 
$(-1)^n\cdot(\pi - \text{A002485}(n)/\text{A002486}(n))
=(|i|\cdot2^j)^{-1} \int_0^1 \big(x^l(1-x)^m(k+(i+k)x^2)\big)/(1+x^2)\; dx$

Comment: Where $m=2(j+2)$